# error when used foreach loop in mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create 2 list **ul** from database. Following my code:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in subCate)
    {
        if (i == 6)
        {
            </ul><ul>
        }
            <li><a href="#">@item.Name</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

but i don't know has error at

> if (i > 6)
>   when i use

```
</ul><ul>
```

but when i replace

```
<li><a href="#">@item.Name</a></li>
```

then not error.
How can i fix? Thanks all.

Comment: Please share the error and what you have tried to resolve it.

Comment: I miss output the un-balanced tags with the `@:</ul><ul>`

Comment: If you want help, you need to share the _exact_ error and what you have tried to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

You have not declared an `i` variable, change it to a `for` loop instead:

```
<ul>
    @for(var i = 0; i < subCate.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == 6)
        {
            @:</ul><ul>
        }
            <li><a href="#">@subCate[i].Name</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

You can also output the un-balanced tags with the `@:`

Comment: yes, I miss output the un-balanced tags with the `@:</ul><ul>`. thanks for suggest

Answer (score 2):

You can continue using your foreach, make sure to check the index of the current item in your collection:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in subCate)
    {
        if (subCate.IndexOf(item) == 6)
        {
            @:</ul><ul>
        }
            <li><a href="#">@item.Name</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```